# formatar dados de uma coluna em um data.frame no R

Tags: r, data.frame

Como se coloca zeros a esquerda em uma coluna de um `data.frame`. No caso, gostaria de formatar os dados para que tivessem 4 caracteres. Ou seja, valores de `24` ficariam `0024`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se usar a função `sprintf`, indicando o formato desejado:

```
dados <- c(1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345)

> sprintf("%04d", dados)
[1] "0001"  "0012"  "0123"  "1234"  "12345"
```

Note que o número de caracteres indicado refere-se ao mínimo; valores maiores não serão cortados.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo utilizando o **dplyr**

```
valores_1 <- c('24','25','34','234','0045', '1234')
dados <- data.frame(Coluna1 = valores_1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

dados %>% mutate( Coluna1 = case_when(
  nchar(Coluna1) == 2 ~ paste0('00',Coluna1),
  nchar(Coluna1) == 3 ~ paste0('0', Coluna1),
  nchar(Coluna1) == 4 ~ Coluna1
))
```

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, essa é uma delas. O **nchar** da o tamanho da string, comparamos e adicionamos a quantidade de 0 necessários.